# Why is my turtle module crashing when I try run Turtle.shape("turtle")?

Tags: python, linux, pycharm

I am trying to code my first OOP turtle object. But When I try to add shape it crashes. My laptop is using Ubuntu 20.04 and running python 3.8. I am using Pycharm. See my code below:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
timmy = Turtle()
my_screen = Screen()
print(my_screen.canvheight)
my_screen.exitonclick()
timmy.shape("classic")
print(timmy)
```

CRASHING MESSAGE OUTPUT

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/turtle.py", line 2779, in shape
    self._update()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/turtle.py", line 2661, in _update
    self._update_data()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/turtle.py", line 2647, in _update_data
    self.screen._incrementudc()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/turtle.py", line 1293, in _incrementudc
    raise Terminator
turtle.Terminator
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem is that you run `shape()` after `exitonclick()` which waits for click and after click it closes window and stops all `turtle` and later it can't work with turtles - so it can't run `timmy.shape()` and this generate your error.

`exitonclick()` is not for stoping code between other tasks. It is only to finish program.

---

**EDIT:**

This work without error

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

timmy = Turtle()

my_screen = Screen()
print(my_screen.canvheight)

timmy.shape("classic")   # <--- before `exitonclick`
print(timmy)

my_screen.exitonclick()
```

And if you want to run something after click then you have to use `.onscreenclick(function)` (without `exitonclick()`) and run code in `function()`

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

# --- functions ---

def function(x, y):
    timmy.shape("classic")
    print('timmy:', timmy)

    # exit program
    my_screen.bye()

# --- main ---
    
timmy = Turtle()

my_screen = Screen()
print(my_screen.canvheight)

my_screen.onscreenclick(function)

# keep running
my_screen.mainloop()
```